# JSP. Кодировка. Корректный вывод символов

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

При переходе с фильтра на jsp страницу, на странице некорректно отображаются русские  символы. Пробовал уже много решений с различных сайтов, но итог один и тот же.

**JSP**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
         Контекст
         <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" method="post">
         <select name="appUserRoleId">
             <c:forEach var="roleItem" items="${userRoles}">
                 <option value="<c:out value="${roleItem.id}"/>">
                     <c:out value="${roleItem.description}"/>
                 </option>
            </c:forEach>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить"></p>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

На jsp пробрасываю массив данных "userRoles", который потом выводятся в выпадающий список. Передаю данный вот так:

```
request.setAttribute("userRoles", user.getAppUserRoleSet());
request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Сами данные я вижу, но вместо букв только знаки вопроса. Что и где я не так указал, для правильной кодировки.

Заранее спасибо

**P.S.** Не может ли это быть связано с тем, что я использую

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

, а не

```
servletResponse.sendRedirect("/MyJSP.jsp");
```

**P.S.S.** Добавление в web.xml EncodingFilter так же не решает проблему

Comment: Расскажите, что уже пробовали? На чем все это запускается?

Comment: пробовал проставлять request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") и аналогично с windows-1251. 

Пробовал прописывать в jsp <% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %> и аналогично с windows-1251.

Менял всё на windows-1251 в jsp.

Разворачиваю через JBoss